# Combining XML Nodes into a single node with an XSLT

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

I'm trying to edit some XML with a transform but I'm struggling to achieve my desired results.

I have some XML:

```
<FX>
   <Order ATTRIBUTE1="ACTIVE" ATTRIBUTE2="CCY" />
   <Attribute NAME="N1" VALUE="V1" />
   <Attribute NAME="N2" VALUE="V2" />
   <Attribute NAME="N3" VALUE="V3" />
</FX>
```

And I want to transform it to look like:

```
<FX>
   <Order ATTRIBUTE1="ACTIVE" ATTRIBUTE2="CCY" />
   <Attribute NAME="N1, N2, N3" VALUE="V1,V2,V3" />
</FX>
```

Is this possible? Can anyone offer any suggestions on how to do this with a transform?

Comment: Your XML is not valid

Comment: Why do you say that? I just used this as an example to show basically what im trying to achieve...

Comment: Because it wasn't valid (before your edit). We cannot guess what would be the correct structure of the XML

Comment: BTW do you really need to use XSLT? Is it Linq to XML an option? Or XML serialization/deserialization?

Comment: I'm trying to do this to avoid needing to make a code change. I have architecture in place to use a transform on incoming XML. If I can achieve my desired results with a transform, it'd be a win.

Comment: Do you know the element is named `FX` and the children you want to merge are named `Attribute` with `NAME` and `VALUE` attributes? Or is the XSLT supposed to identify siblings with the same name and attributes to merge them? Also in the .NET world you have access to Microsoft's XSLT 1 processor `XslCompiledTransform` but also to third party XSLT 2 or 3 processors, doing things in XSLT 2 or 3 is easier than in the 20 year old XSLT 1.

Comment: Got it. I'm afraid I can't help you, it's been a loooooong time since I used XSLT. I'd avoid it like the plague, its syntax is not very friendly and it's not that easy to test/debug. Good luck!

Comment: The Elements will always be named as they are displayed. The root will always be named FX and the nodes that repeat will always be named ATTRIBUTE which will always contain attributes called NAME and VALUE. Basically I want the entire XML to remain exactly the same. I just want to remove the N number of ATTRIBUTE nodes and replace them with a single node that has the NAME and Values comma separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following, Asp.NET compatable, XSLT-1.0 stylesheet to perform an XSLT transformation from your source XML to your destination XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/FX">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Order" />
        <Attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="NAME">
                <xsl:for-each select="Attribute">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@NAME" />
                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="VALUE">
                <xsl:for-each select="Attribute">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@VALUE" />
                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </Attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Its output is:**

```
<FX>
  <Order ATTRIBUTE1="ACTIVE" ATTRIBUTE2="CCY"/>
  <Attribute NAME="N1, N2, N3" VALUE="V1,V2,V3"/>
</FX>
```

Comment: Thanks! this is so close to what I need. The goal is regarless of what the XML looks like, I want it to remain untouched with the exception of removing all of the repeating ATTRIBUTE nodes and replace it with a single ATTRIBUTE node that contains all the Name/Value pairs from the original message in comma separated attributes for NAME/VALUE.

Comment: Thanks for this response though, its a great start! Appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean by "close". The result is exactly what you requested in the question.

Comment: I pretty much took apart the XML i'm actually using to try to just illistrate what I want to happen. My actual XML has a bunch of nodes (that will sometimes appear in the XML and sometimes won't). I am basically trying to keep the XML exactly as it comes in, with the only change being manipulating the Attribute nodes and condensing them into a single node. Sorry, I should have been more clear in my post. In any event, I really appreciate your time and your response.

Comment: I replaced the line: <xsl:copy-of select="Order" /> with   <xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()" />. Now I get an exact copy of my XML with the addition of my desired new Attribute node that has the csv name/value pairs. I just need to remove the original ones now.

Comment: Try `<xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()[not(self::Attribute)]" />` to remove the doublettes. And don't forget to accept my answer if that did help you.

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much my friend. Exactly what I needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to transform some nodes but keep the rest you use the identity transformation template as the starting point and then add templates that change those nodes you want to change:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="FX/Attribute[1]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="FX/Attribute[position() > 1]"/>

  <xsl:template match="FX/Attribute[1]/@*">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
          <xsl:for-each select=". | ../following-sibling::Attribute/@*[name() = name(current())]">
              <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rNk

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Your time is very much appreciated!